# Is there any OpenAL effects GUI editor?

Tags: user-interface, openal

I have a project where I use OpenAL and effects extension (EXTEfx). For example have something like this:

```
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MIN_DECAY_TIME, 0.1f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MAX_DECAY_TIME, 20.0f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_DEFAULT_DECAY_TIME, 1.49f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MIN_DECAY_HFRATIO, 0.1f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MAX_DECAY_HFRATIO, 2.0f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_DEFAULT_DECAY_HFRATIO, 0.83f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MIN_REFLECTIONS_GAIN, 0.0f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MAX_REFLECTIONS_GAIN, 3.16f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_DEFAULT_REFLECTIONS_GAIN, 0.05f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MIN_REFLECTIONS_DELAY, 0.0f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MAX_REFLECTIONS_DELAY, 0.3f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_DEFAULT_REFLECTIONS_DELAY, 0.007f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MIN_LATE_REVERB_GAIN, 0.0f);
alEffectf(id, AL_REVERB_MAX_LATE_REVERB_GAIN, 10.0f);
```

The problem is that I have to recompile and restart my program each time I change a parameter. I'd like to play around with effects settings in real time to find a better sound, and hear the difference immediately.

Is there any GUI editor where I could load my audio sample and adjust some of these values and other effects as well, and then just copy values in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My friend has found "OpenAL 1.1 Core SDK" which is exactly what I was looking for. It is available [here](https://www.openal.org/downloads/).

[image: EFX 10 Show]

Comment: The binary for this app is in the SDK under samples/bin, and to run it you need the Visual Studio 2005 (8.0) redistributable. It will fail to start with a 'side by side configuration is incorrect' error if you don't have the redist.